# Reshaping of Array in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have a 32768*8 array which I want to convert into a 1*262144 array. I have used the MATLAB command reshape but the problem is reshape changes the matrix row-wise and then appends it to the columns. I have also used the (V:); function but it also does the same as reshape so no use.

I want that the binary data integrity is maintained. So
 0F 4B = 0000 1111 0100 1011...etc should be like this and not otherwise as done by the reshape command.

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: Is it a char array or double array or some other array? Get us the `whos` info on it?

Comment: Could you please write a (small) example (array 2*8 for example) of what you expect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also transpose your matrix first then invoke the `(:)` command too!  Make sure you transpose your vector back if you want it to be a row vector.

```
MyMatrix = MyMatrix.';
MyVector = (MyMatrix(:)).';
```

Also to be syntactically correct (inspired by Dan - see below), I have also employed `.'` as using `'` will invoke the *complex transpose*.  Not only will it transpose your vector, it will also *conjugate* your elements as well.  This is actually quite useful if you want to calculate the magnitude of a complex vector, as the definition of the magnitude squared is `(a + ib)*(a - ib)`.  If I remember correctly, an article by Loren Shure (I can't remember which one) mentioned that the complex transpose was placed in MATLAB for this very purpose.

However, if all of your elements are real, then you can either use `'` or `.'`.  Doesn't matter which one.

Comment: You must also transpose your final result again to get a row vector instead of a column vector

Comment: @KashifNawaz: Though I'm flattered you have accepted my answer, Dan's answer is much more elegant and is only one line.  I still don't mind the accept though :)

Answer (score 5):

If you want to reshape it in row major order, just transpose first:

```
reshape(MyMatrix.', 1, [])
```

So the `.'` is the crux of the solution here. (Note that if you're not working with complex numbers then `'` and `.'` do the same thing. I just used `.'` to be completely correct, but in the vast majority of cases I would just use `'`)

Comment: yeps!! it works...i transposed it earlier and was then doing a reshape..but this single step solution is better!!

Comment: A fervent +1 for "I just used `.'` to be completely correct"

Answer (score 3):

I would definitely use `reshape` or `:` as in previous answers. But, if you have the Communications Toolbox, you can also use [`vec2mat`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/comm/ref/vec2mat.html):

```
vec2mat(MyMatrix, numel(MyMatrix))
```